# Debug.WriteLine malfunctions in Visual Studio. How to fix it?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

The text sent is not seen in the `Output` window.

`Solution Configuration` is `Debug`.

`Output window` is showing output from `Debug`.

It's a simple command: `Debug.WriteLine("abc");`

Setting a `Breakpoint` on it succeeds, but the program breaks on the line after it, moving the `Breakpoint`!

Changing `Platform` from `Any CPU` to `x86` solves the issue. But going back, it returns.

Creating a new solution, it *does* work. Even in `Any CPU`.

I removed the `.suo` file for the solution.

I emptied the `%temp%` folder.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Do you have the "Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window" option checked in the Debugging options?

Comment: No. And now I tried that and it didn't appear there either.

Comment: Take a look at my solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992094/debug-writeline-stops-working/12931631#12931631


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992094/debug-writeline-stops-working/12931631#12931631

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to Build -> Configuration manager and make sure you are in Debug mode, not Release.
2) Right-click on the project that you're having trouble with and choose properties.
3) Check the Build tab and make sure **Define DEBUG constant** and **Define TRACE constant** are both **checked**.

Note, most people make the mistake corrected by Step #1.  But in my case it was steps #2 and #3 that fixed the problem.  Despite being in DEBUG mode, for some reason those two constants were not being defined!  I think the IDE may have turned them off when I had some of the projects in a solution using one platform target, and the rest of them using a different one, because by default, they are both enabled (checked) when you are in Debug mode.