# System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine giving no output in Visual Studio 2015 even though settings set to display

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015

As the title suggests, I'm getting no outup in VS2015 from a line such as :

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("***************************************Terst output");

I've checked my Output window is set to display this (debug category).

I've had a many a google. Is there any obvious setting I may be missing? Thanks in advance for your input!

Comment: Are you in release or debug mode?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you press <kbd>F5</kbd> to Start Debugging mode (not <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>).

> <kbd>F5</kbd> Starting Debugging
>
> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> Starting Without Debugging

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure you have added the correct references.  (Add references -> System, System.dll).
2. Check release config (make sure build type is Debug).
3. Ensure you are not building a Portable Class Libraries or ".NET for Metro style apps".

See related answers:

[Missing reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845828/missing-reference-to-system-diagnostics-process)

[Why does System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine not work in VS2010 C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000507/why-does-system-diagnostics-debug-writeline-not-work-in-vs2010-c-sharp)

Comment: In addition @drones comments ensure that the output source is set to "Debug".