# System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine not schon in debug mode in output window (Ctrl+Alt+O)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, ide

I accidently closed the output window in VS2013.
After quite some time I found the Ctrl+Alt+O - shurtcut to get the output window back.

Since then System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine output is not shown there.
The project is set to build "Debug" and Output-Window is set to show output from debug.
Any Idea? Thank you

Edit: I tried [Debug.Writeline stops working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992094/debug-writeline-stops-working/6285021)

Line is hit when using a breakpoint, Platform tried Any/mixed/x86 - all with no output

Edit2: There is no "clear" in app.config, However a FileLogWriter. Removing that does not solve the problem either

"Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window" in
Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General. is enabled

Console.Write does not work as well ( I read that Console.Write does only work for Console applications?!)

Right-click in the output window "Program output" is checked.

Sysinternals DebugView Shows the output

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370449/debug-writeline-not-working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1159766/2882256

Comment: Many solutions, I found most of them before. But the other ones solved the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The output window was teh wrong place to look at.
DEBUG-->WINDOW-->IMMEDIATE
Important setting:
 "Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window" under 
Tools > Options > Debugging > General. To display "Tools > Options > Debugging", (need check the box next to "Tools > Options > Show All Settings")

by bluish and boardernin, [Where does System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write output appear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159755/where-does-system-diagnostics-debug-write-output-appear/1159766)